# how to get request of flask in decorator logger?

Tags: python, flask, decorator

I want writing log about query strings and form data of request object in flask.

I use decorator function for logging.

**customlog.py**

```
import logging

def webLog(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def newFunc(*args, **kwargs):
        logging.debug(request.url + " : " + str(request.remote_addr))
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return newFunc
```

**main.py**

```
@app.route('/')
@customlog.webLog
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

but, request in main.py, another source file.

How to get request object for logging?
Using parameters of decorator function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can just add the following import `from flask import request` to `customlog.py`. Here's the test code I used that worked. I just replaced `logging.debug` with a simple print statement for testing.

```
from functools import wraps
from flask import request

def webLog(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def newFunc(*args, **kwargs):
        print request.url + " : " + str(request.remote_addr)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return newFunc
```